# Keeping slider open when rebinding grid using AJAX in asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, slider, radajaxmanager

I am using [this slider](http://nnattawat.github.io/slideReveal/) on a page in my asp.net webforms application. The slider users jQuery to simply open and close a div on the page. The content in this slider div is an asp.net repeater that lists a bunch of Link buttons.

I have a grid in the main div on my page.

When a link button is clicked in the LinkButton_OnClick server-event I am calling rebind on the grid and updating the datasource to be filtered by the value that they clicked on.

Can someone give me an idea of how I can keep the slider open and still rebind the grid?

I already trying wrapping the slider div in an ASP.NET Panel and wrapping the grid div in an ASP.NET Panel. Then using a Telerik:RadAjaxManager to say that pnlSlider updates pnlGrid, but I am still getting a page refresh instead of Ajax being used.

Comment: Do you try to wrap the repeater in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: This worked. Before I was wrapping the entire slider div in a panel and the grid in a panel. It works when I wrap each repeater that is inside  the main slider div inside of a panel and then the grid in a panel.